# UWP and InkToolbar: how to draw basic shapes

Tags: xaml, uwp, draw, shapes, inkcanvas

I work on a UWP app where the user must be able to take a photo from the camera, and add details by drawing some shapes. I think the simplest way to do this is using the **InkToolbar**. So I've donwloaded the official sample: [SimpleInk](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk)

But I don't see how to solve some of my needs:

- add a background image to the InkCanvas:  I would like get a **BitmapImage** containing the original photo and the items drawed by the user

***=> is it possible to do this properly? or do I need to superpose the Image and the InkCanvas in the Grid and take a screenshot?***

- draw basic shapes like circles or rectangles: all the samples are based on hand drawing with different kinds of pencils

***=> is there a way to draw shapes like circles or rectangles through this control? or what is the better way for allowing user to "draw" shapes easily?***

I also looked at the Win2D samples [Win2D-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-samples), but I didn't found a similar case.

Thanks in advance for your feedbacks!

Answer (score 1):

> add a background image to the InkCanvas: I would like get a BitmapImage containing the original photo and the items drawed by the user

The `InkCanvas` doesn't contain a `background` property directly. You can create an `InkCanvas`  overlays a background image by using an `Image` control like the [Basic inking with InkCanvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/pen-and-stylus-interactions#basic-inking-with-inkcanvas) sample shows.

But if you need to get a new BitmapImage from original image with `InkCanvas` drawing you need to use the [Win2D](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Win2D.uwp) library. For more details and a completed demo please reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179815/displaying-a-background-image-on-a-uwp-ink-canvas).

> draw basic shapes like circles or rectangles: all the samples are based on hand drawing with different kinds of pencils

For this, the [UAP](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/tree/master/SimpleSample/UAP) sample of [`Win2D-samples`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/tree/master/SimpleSample/UAP) you mentioned above provided a demo for drawing a circle you can reference(same with `rectangles` like follows).

```
args.DrawingSession.DrawEllipse(155, 115, 80, 30, Colors.Black, 3);    
args.DrawingSession.DrawRectangle(155, 115, 80, 30, Colors.Black);
```

The official [Complex inking sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ComplexInk) also provide the `Insert a shape` feature you can test and reference.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
But I need to draw the shapes manually: by drag and drop or a click, and then adjust the size by moving the ends of the shape (like with the decorators in WPF).
Is this easily feasable in an UWP app?
I found a componenant that must allowing me to do this:
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp/diagram
But the final customer must bought a license...